# How to resize the background canvas size to the size of the layer in Gimp

Tags: gimp, resize, canvas

How to reduce the background canvas size to the layer size.
I used `Image > Fit canvas to layers` but it does not do this.

In Fireworks there was a button named `Fit To Canvas` for doing this. I searching this in Gimp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In GIMP, [*Fit Canvas to layers*](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-image-resize-to-layers.html) resizes the canvas by taking into account the largest layer and all the other layers. So the reason it has failed means that you must have a layer that's bigger than the layer/layers you were expecting it to be resized to. At a guess, and without seeing your file or arrangement of layers, I'd say that's probably your background layer.

To fix it, remove the layer that's filling the canvas, then repeat the *Fit Canvas to layers*.

Alternatively, if you don't want to remove any layers, select the layer you wish to use for resizing the canvas, and in the layers panel right click it and choose *Aplha to Selection*, then click *Image > Crop to Selection*.

Note that cropping in GIMP is destructive, and it will crop the background layer if there is one, so you may wish to save your XCF file, and work on a copy before doing any of these operations.

Comment: No need to crop, there is also an `Image>Fit canvas to selection` function.

Comment: @xenoid Yes there is!  Forgot that one. Thanks for reminding me.